# Can't find Apt-Cacher NG cache files after performing Ubuntu preseed installation using cacher as proxy

Tags: system-installation, repository, preseed, localrepository, apt-cacher-ng

I've setup Apt-Cacher NG in an Ubuntu host. I'm using this to cache another Ubuntu installation and setup a repo for further installations. I've tried installing Ubuntu through preseed file bellow, pointing to cacher proxy. I can't find cached .deb files. Are they being cached?

Preseed file:

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i time/zone string UTC

d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto


d-i mirror/country string enter information manually
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 10.0.2.2:3142
d-i mirror/http/directory string /archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu


d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string \
        scheme ::                     \
        200 0 200 ext4                \
                $primary{ }           \
                $bootable{ }          \
                method{ format }      \
                format{ }             \
                use_filesystem{ }     \
                filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                mountpoint{ /boot } . \
        200% 0 200% linux-swap        \
                $primary{ }           \
                method{ swap }        \
                format{ } .           \
        1 0 -1 ext4                   \
                $primary{ }           \
                method{ format }      \
                format{ }             \
                use_filesystem{ }     \
                filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                mountpoint{ / } .
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

d-i base-installer/excludes string laptop-detect
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-server

d-i clock-setup/utc-auto boolean true
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string US/Pacific
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true

d-i mirror/country string US
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i pkgsel/install-language-support boolean false
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect standard, ubuntu-desktop

d-i pkgsel/include string curl sudo ubuntu-desktop
d-i pkgsel/language-packs multiselect

d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think you need to set `mirror/http/proxy` to your apt-cacher-ng host as well otherwise it is probably using the country specific version of the archive.ubuntu.org mirror which may not match the mirror URL you specified. The downside of the mirror/http/proxy is that it affects ALL http downloads (wget/curl/etc) for the duration of the preseed.</del>

Actually after further reading you should leave the country as literally `country string manual`. Manual doesn't mean 'replace me' in this instance, it means don't automatically pick a mirror (the default behavior) and this is actually why you weren't seeing any traffic on your apt-cacher-ng host, the system was simply bypassing it and going to the local regional mirror instead.